# Is it possible to deploy a JSF 2.1.x webapp on a Weblogic 10.3.6 (Servlet 2.5) if my webapp use only JSF 2.0.x features?

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic-10.x

I want to upgrade JSF version from 2.0.x to 2.1.x only for avoiding a bug that cause @ViewScope bean to destroy when any primefaces ajax request from the browser is made.

I have tested all my project's use cases and no errors are shown. All work like a charm.

So, is it possible to deploy a JSF 2.1.x application on a weblogic 10.3.6 even though it is only a 2.5 Servlet web container when using only JSF 2.0.x features?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I did not explain it very well: "I have tested all my project's use cases and no errors are shown. All work like a charm" using JSF 2.1.24 and Weblogic 10.3.6. I would like to know if there are known issues when using only JSF 2.0.x features.